# change selected color on xamarin listview w

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

Very green Android developer here.  I have a handheld Zebra scanner I am trying to develop an android application for.  I have mapped the volume buttons to scroll through a listview, but the only way I can tell it is indeed scrolling is to put the selected item's text in an EditText.  I would like for the selected item to be highlighted instead (similar to touching an item).  Is this possible?  Below is the code I am using for the volume keys.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if (keyCode == Android.Views.Keycode.VolumeDown)
{
    if (scrollItem < itemList.Count - 1)
    {
        scrollItem += 1;
        itemListView.RequestFocusFromTouch();
        itemList.SetSelection(scrollItem);
        item = partsAdapter.GetItemAtPosition(scrollItem);
        itemEditText.Text = item.partNbr;
        saveItemDesc = item.partDescription;
    }
    return true;
}

//scroll up through parts listing
if (keyCode == Android.Views.Keycode.VolumeUp)
{
    if (scrollItem > 0)
    {
        scrollItem -= 1;
        itemList.SetSelection(scrollItem);
        item = partsAdapter.GetItemAtPosition(scrollItem);
        itemEditText.Text = item.partNbr;
        saveItemDesc = item.partDescription;
    }
    return true;
}

OnCreate...
{
    ...
    itemList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.itemListView);
    partsAdapter = new PartsAdapter(this);
    itemList.Adapter = partsAdapter;
    itemList.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;
    itemList.OnItemClickListener = new ListListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like for the selected item to be highlighted

Add the following line in your `ListView` item layout :

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_key"
```

Define `bg_key.xml` in `Drawable` folder like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/pressed_color"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
</selector>
```

Then, add the `OnItemClickListener` in your `ListView` :

```
listView.OnItemClickListener = new MyListener(this);

public class MyListener : Java.Lang.Object, AdapterView.IOnItemClickListener
{
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public MyListener(MainActivity mainActivity)
    {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    public void OnItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        view.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

This way, only one item will be color-selected at any time. You can define your color values in `Resource/values/colors.xml` with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="pressed_color">#4d90fe</color>
    <color name="default_color">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: This is working if I touch an item (which is further than I have gotten before), but not when I hit the side volume keys.  At what point am I adding the listener to the listview?  I am currently putting it in OnCreate after FindViewByID, Adapter, and ChoieMode lines (added above).

Comment: I got this to work for me now.  I added ListView.RequestFocusFromTouch();  
(added to initial code)  Thanks for showing me the door.  I would upvote your answer, but it won't let me.